# Adding Linker Flags in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, gmp

(I'm not sure if "flag" is the word I'm looking for, but I'll explain it.)

I am trying to compile a program that uses the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) big number library. But to be able to compile with GMP, I have to add `-lgmp` to the end of the command. For example, if I want to compile "program.c", I have to type `gcc program.c -lgmp`. This is easy from the command line, but I don't see how to do it in Xcode. How can I add the `lgmp` flag while using Xcode?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Right-click the target in the Xcode **Groups and Files** list and select **Get Info** from the contextual menu. In the **Build** tab, type `linker` into the search field and then locate the **Other Linker Flags** item.

Double-click the **Other Linker Flags** item and add `-lgmp`.

Comment: What does one do when adding those flags then don't actually kick in? (looking at the compile log the flags I add are not passed to clang at all. The same goes for header and library paths)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

> You can also open the active target's preferences, and click the "General" tab. You can add the library to be linked inside that tab, in the "Linked Libraries" section at the botton.

Taken from http://www.soulstorm-creations.com/PROJECT_SOULSTORM_2_0/programming-articles/installing-portable-libraries-on-os-x.html

Answer (score 1):

You can just open the folder containing `libgmp.a` on your system (`/usr/local/lib/` for a default install), and drag the library out of the folder onto the target that you want it to get linked into.  There are several other ways as well, such as the one suggested by **Zitrax**.