# Using GMP in Xcode 4 -- linking problems

Tags: xcode4, gmp

I am trying to use the GMP 5.0.2 libraries in a demo C++ project in Xcode 4.0.2, but I'm having trouble getting the linking to work.

I looked at the comments in the StackOverflow post: [Adding Linker Flags in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125079/adding-compile-flags-in-xcode), 
found the GMP library and header files in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include and dragged them to the project target.  This allowed the project to compile, but apparently not to link.  The error I'm getting is

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator>>(std::istream&, __mpz_struct*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions for what I should try next?  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gmp.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    mpz_t x;
    mpz_init(x);
    cin >> x;
    cout << "x = " << endl;

    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To run your program with GMP, remember to add the `-lgmp` flag to the linker, like so: (via [Rob Keniger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138033/52573)):

> Right-click the target in the Xcode **Groups and Files** list and select **Get Info** from the contextual menu. In the **Build** tab, type `linker` into the search field and then locate the **Other Linker Flags** item.
>
> Double-click the **Other Linker Flags** item and add `-lgmp`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1) As nes says, be sure to add the -lgmp flag to your linker call.
2) Try including "gmpxx.h" and adding -lgmpxx -lgmp to the linker. (The order can be important!) It shouldn't be necessary for straight C code...in theory...but those look more like C++ errors to me.
3) Consider the MPIR library. It is the same as GMP but with a more Windows friendly view of the world.
4) Check the manual - sometimes there are other includes you need for specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

How was your GMP library compiled? Was it compiled for 32-bit architectures only by any chance? If so, you won't be able to use it in a 64-bit project; you'll have to add `-arch i386` to the list of compiler flags to make XCode create a 32-bit executable.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:

1. project
2. build phases
3. link binary with librarys
4. click "+" choose your own gmp library,like /opt/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (ps:I use macport to complie GMP).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need all of the features of GMP, you should be able to simply drag and drop the `mini-gmp.h` and `mini-gmp.m` files into your project and start using the basic features of the library.