# c++: compile with library argument in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, gmp

In terminal, this works:

`g++ -lgmp main.cpp`

while this does not:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

I am using X-code as my IDE and how could I tell X-code to add the statement '-lgmp' when compiling? Thank you:)

Edit: I did according to the article providing the answer:
[image]

but I still fail:

[image]

and this is the error message:
[image]

More information:
I have to use c++98 instead of c++11 because one of my package Gurobi requires that. Do you know any solution? thank you:)

Comment: Is the `gmp` lib you're using a `dylib` installed on the system, or a static lib? There are several ways to do what you're trying, one of them particularly easy if you're using a dylib. Apart from that, [**see this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125079/adding-linker-flags-in-xcode?rq=1), which is nearly identical to yours).

Comment: Oh... Thank you, actually I am very new in c++ and I am actually not sure what that means....

Comment: That method doesn't work... I edited my post to provide more information:)